# Get data from newest files in a Google Drive Folder to another Google Spreadsheet in the same folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I use an app to export some date to a Google Drive Folder, every time my app runs, it exports a CSV to a specific folder in Google Drive. I would need help to be able to automate the process and more precisely: the data from the newest CSV export to be automatically taken over by another file (MASTER-SHEET) located in the same folder.

I try some functions in Apps Script but I am new on this and some help from you are necessary.

I also try this script:

```
function importData()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("{MASTERSHEET_ID}");
  var folderID = '{GOOGLE_DRIVE_FOLDER_ID}';
  var fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var files = fldr.getFilesByType('text/csv');
  while (files.hasNext())
  {
    var file = files.next();
    var fileName = file.getName();
    if(file.getBlob().getContentType() === "text/csv" && !fileName.match(/.old/))
    {
      var csvstr=file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
      var csvData=Utilities.parseCsv(csvstr);
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("MASTERSHEET_SHEET1");
    }
  }
}
```

After i hit run I dont get any error, but also no result in the Sheet1 of the MasterSheet.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to ask a specific programming question e.g. show us what you've tried and what is the error (if any) you're getting or where you're stuck. Your question is essentially currently asking for an entire solution and Stackoverflow isn't tailored for that.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow! Please take this opportunity to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn how to [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [format the code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [etc](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function findMostRecentCsv() {
  const fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById(gobj.globals.gpstracksfolderid);//change folderid
  const files = fldr.getFilesByType(MimeType.CSV);
  const fA = [];
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    fA.push(files.next())
  }
  fA.sort((a,b)=> {
    return b.getDateCreated().valueOf() - a.getDateCreated().valueOf()
  })
  Logger.log(fA[0].getName());
  return fA[0];
}

function loadCSVInSpreadsheet() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(gobj.globals.ssid);//change id to destination spreadsheet
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");//change name to dest sheet
  sh.clearContents();//not sure if  you will want this
  const csv = findMostRecentCsv().getBlob().getDataAsString();
  const a = Utilities.parseCsv(csv);
  sh.getRange(1,1,a.length,a[0].length).setValues(a);

}
```

Comment: Run the second function and your csv will be loaded in the spreadsheet of your choice

Comment: By the way I never bother to read code placed into a comment.  You have a perfectly wonder question you can post the code into and format it properly so that someone can read it very easily.  I'd suggest using it.

Comment: I tested both of these.

Comment: Thanks Cooper! I update my original post with what code I use...

Comment: Yeah mine doesn't depend upon the filename.  It gets it's information from the file itself

Comment: I try the only "function loadCSVInSpreadsheet()"...but I get "An unknown error has occurred, please try again later."

Comment: There are two function the one on the bottom calls the one on the top and you will have to edit both of the with sheets names and id's

Comment: I put both functions and also get the same error. Obviously I replaced the IDs and the Sheet name. Any suggestion?   Exemple: **gobj.globals.ssid ->gobj.globals.ss{myid)**

Comment: I also get the error **ReferenceError: gobj is not defined
findMostRecentCsv**

Comment: Yes you are supposed to replace `gobj.globals.gpstracksfolderid` with your folder id,  It's a string so put quotations around it.

Comment: And the same is true for `gobj.globals.ssid` it's a spreadsheet id and it's a string to so put quotes around it

Comment: And `Sheet0` replace it with name of the sheet you wish to write to